# systemd service file for cardano node

Tags: cardano-node

i'm trying to run a node as a service using `systemctl start node-relay.service`

i get this error, can anyone advise what i'm doing wrong.

`/home/ec2-user/.local/bin/cardano-node: error while loading shared libraries: libsodium.so.23: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

my node-relay.service file looks like this

```
Description= relay node
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/home/ec2-user/relay/node.environment
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/.local/bin/cardano-node run --config $CONFIG --topology $TOPOLOGY --database-path $DBPATH --socket-path $SOCKETPATH --host-addr $HOSTADDR --port $PORT
KillSignal = SIGINT
RestartKillSignal = SIGINT
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
SyslogIdentifier=cardano-node

LimitNOFILE=32768

Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=15s
WorkingDirectory=~
User=ec2-user
Group=ec2-user

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

my .bashrc file contains

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
export PATH="~/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

the node starts fine if it run it like this;

`cardano-node run --config ~/relay/testnet-config.json --database-path ~/relay/db --socket-path ~/relay/db/node.socket --host-addr 0.0.0.0 --port 3000`

Comment: Are you aware of this post: https://forum.cardano.org/t/error-cardano-node-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libsodium-so-23-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory/39820 ? It refers to another one here https://forum.cardano.org/t/updating-stake-pool-school-config-files/37749/14 which recommends more or less what you did but with an additional step. Worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variables need to be added to the `/home/ec2-user/relay/node.environment` file. Or you can specify them directly in `node-relay.service` file.

```
[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
Environment="PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"

...
```

Comment: thanks, all makes sense now.